# AFNetworking-2 with Trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io, afnetworking-2

I'm building a trigger.io native module and included the AFNetworking 2.0 framework by manually adding the header and implementation files into the ForgeModule project.

AFNetworking 2.0 [indicates](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#requirements) a target requirement of ios 6.0+.

In xcode, i've changed the deployment target for the `UniversalForgeModule` to `6.0`.

Yet after including this newly packaged native module in my app, I get the following error upon building it:

```
Ld build/Release-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.app/Forge normal i386
    cd /var/folders/xw/34h86n3d5p54qpq1wfc8ff600000b1/T/tmp5z_JZJ/ios/app
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0.1
```

...

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  _UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      -[AFStreamingMultipartFormData appendPartWithFileURL:name:error:] in frisbees.a(AFURLRequestSerialization.o)
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      -[AFStreamingMultipartFormData appendPartWithFileURL:name:error:] in frisbees.a(AFURLRequestSerialization.o)
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      -[AFStreamingMultipartFormData appendPartWithFileURL:name:error:] in frisbees.a(AFURLRequestSerialization.o)
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      -[AFStreamingMultipartFormData appendPartWithFileURL:name:error:] in frisbees.a(AFURLRequestSerialization.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
  Ld build/Release-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.app/Forge normal i386
(1 failure)
```

Looks like my build target is still `5.0.1`. How do I go about changing that?

Full logs available [here](http://pastebin.com/QPyCfR7w).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems AFNetworking 2.0 is referencing the Apple Framework: MobileCoreServices.framework.

To include Apple frameworks to your module, you will need to [Change build configuration](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/native_build_steps.html) by adding an `add_ios_system_framework` build step.

Steps:

1. Add a `build_steps.json` file to the `ios` folder within your module directory.
2. Add the following to the file:

   ```
   [ 
     {
       "do": {
         "add_ios_system_framework": {
             "framework": "MobileCoreServices.framework"
          }
        }
     }
   ]
   ```
3. Update your inspector project, so that the newly added build step is applied to your project.

Comment: Thanks Clive! Unfortunately when I do include it I receive duplicate symbol errors, which I believe indicates it's already present. I looked through my other modules and did not find it though. Don't you think this error is related to the deployment target ios version?

Comment: Do you have the forge.request module enabled in your app by any chance?

Forge.request also uses AFNetworking which may be the cause of symbol clashes as we still haven't found a good solution to deal with iOS only supporting static linking.

Otherwise, could you give a bit more detail on the duplicate symbol errors?

Comment: What's odd is that I only ended up seeing those duplicate symbols when I include MobileCoreServices, not when I included the AFNetworking library. Full logs above in my initial post.

Comment: I did a quick spike and was successfully able to incorporate AFNetworking into a native module for trigger.io. I was also able to successfully call my API method on the iOS Simulator whilst running the ForgeInspector project. Along with the answer steps I had to add an additional build step: `add_ios_system_framework` to include the framework `Security.framework` and had to update the `iOS Deployment Target` of the ForgeModule to `iOS 6.0`.